# Método Accept de Connect se sigue activando continuamente

Tags: c#, socket

Tengo un servidor que recibe una conexión vía Socket el cuál pongo en un ciclo infinito (while(true)) de manera que reciba tantas conexiones como sean necesarias. El código es éste.

```
                while (true) {
                LcSktClient = LcServer.Socket.Accept();
                oClient = new Client(LcSktClient, LcEventos, EventLog, LcSql);
                SbAddEvent("Se ha conectado un Cliente.", 0, "Information", oClient.ToString());
                oClient.SbStart();
                LcClientes.Add(oClient.Celda, oClient);
            }
```

el Socket devuelto (LcSktClient) lo almaceno en un objeto oClient en el cuál ejecuto una función (SbStart) que tiene ésta estructura.

```
        public void SbStart() {
        //## Control de Errores
        string StrSysFuncion = string.Concat(LcSysClase, ".SbStart");
        //## Control de Errores

        try {
            LcAMTN.ConnectToServer(true);
            LcTimer = new Timer(SbProcess);
            _ = LcTimer.Change(0, LcIntPollingTimer);
            //SbProcess(null);
            SbAddEvent("Se ha iniciado la tarea de Cliente.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.Source = string.Concat(StrSysFuncion, "<", ex.Source);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

La función básicamente arranca asíncronamente un método que es el que se encarga de "Escuchar" un Control AMTN (una especie de PLC) que, cuando recibe una señal, debe enviarla al cliente conectado.

```
        private void SbProcess(object StateInfo) {
        //## Control de Errores
        string StrSysFuncion = string.Concat(LcSysClase, ".SbProcess");
        //## Control de Errores

        EnmTipoPulsacion TipoPulsacion;
        Task oTask;

        try {
            TipoPulsacion = FnValidateAMTNControl();
            if (TipoPulsacion != EnmTipoPulsacion.SinPulsacion) {
                _ = LcSktClient.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(((int)TipoPulsacion).ToString()));
                oTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SbAddEvent("Se envió pulsación al cliente.", 0, pStrData: $"Pulsación: {TipoPulsacion}"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.Source = string.Concat(StrSysFuncion, "<", ex.Source);
            SbAddEvent("Ocurrió un error al procesar el cliente.", 0, "Error", $"{ex.Message}; En: {ex.Source}");
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

El problema es que, cuando el primer cliente se conecta, tengo entendido que se libera la función Accept, que se encarga de crear el Socket cliente y después el resto, luego el ciclo infinito hace que se vuelva a llegar al Socket Servidor y ejecute otro Accept, dónde en teoría debería detenerse hasta que surja un nuevo cliente que se conecte... o ésto es lo que yo tengo entendido,  pero no es el caso, la función pasa de nuevo sin detenerse y se crea un nuevo Socket cliente... que es el mismo que se había conectado al inicio. Sin embargo, el cliente no se reconectó ni perdió su conexión inicial... alguna idea??

Gracias.